# Why do we need Boolean(String) constructor?

Tags: java, standard-library

I'm wondering because I think that behaviour of this constructor isn't as obvious as other wrappers constructors. It's not difficult but more clear to use bool constructor `new Boolean ("true".equalsIgnoreCase(str))` as for me.

So, is there any common use-case for it (maybe somewhere inside standard library) or was it written only for uniformity with other wrappers?

Comment: There's a lot of bloat in standard packages, especially in old classes.

Comment: does it also support "T" / "F" ?  Possibly parsing booleans in results from a database are one use-case?

Comment: No. From the Docs: Allocates a Boolean object representing the value true if the string argument is not null and is equal, ignoring case, to the string "true". And the implementation: `return ((name != null) && name.equalsIgnoreCase("true"));`

Comment: I'm not sure after all it's a good question for SO as the answer would probably be something like *"Well, it seemed a good idea at that time. You know we didn't even think about char encoding, he..."*. Maybe for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ ?